# SQL Return Specific Value for Duplicate rows

Tags: sql, distinct

Here is my issue

I am using bulk import to import a CSV file into a table (InputTable). This table needs to be separated into 3 different tables with distinct values.

Tables are Client, Child Company, Contacts

Client has a one to many relationship to child company as well as to contacts.

The client Table has has two fields (name,status)

it is easy enough to pull in a distinct name from dbo.InputTable using this query...

```
    insert into Client
    (
Name
    )
    select distinct Name
    from InputTable
```

this query will insert data like this

```
Name

One Company

Two Company

Three Company
```

However when i try this code

```
    insert into Client
    (
 Name
     ,Status

    )
    select distinct Name
    from InputTable
    group by Name
    ,Status
```

I get this result

```
Name         | Status

One Company       | Active

Two Company       | Active

Two Company       | Terminated

Three Company     | Active
```

Here is the kicker, If client is showing active in one row no matter how many rows then i need to show active for that Name record on the Client Table

if they are showin all terminated then i would need to copy in the terminated status to the client table for that row.

any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: What if you had multiple rows each with a different status, none of which being "active"?

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into Client (Name, status)
select name,
    min(status) as status
from InputTable 
group by name
```

Comment: This solution works great by using the alphabet for the distinction...what would you do if you have more than two status indicators. for example Active, inactive, internal, impl, and terminated....please disregard. this works GREAT! thank you!

Comment: @user1535018 I can't say as I don't know how you choose between other statuses. Please provide updated sample data and desired output.